# Count number of elements within Objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Submission Model and using a query, I get a list of all Submissions.  Then in order to get into each submission, I use a loop

```
foreach ($submissions as $submission) {

}
```

Each submission has the following elements

```
[original:protected] => Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [sessionKey]  => dfshduifhsduifhsdiu
    [number]      => 9
    [isCompleted] => 0
    [created_at]  => 2017-07-29 23:14:02
    [updated_at]  => 2017-07-30 00:04:00
)
```

What I am trying to do is produce an array which outputs some details about all of the submissions.  First thing I need is the total number of submissions.  Next I need the number of complete (isComplete = 1) and incomplete (isComplete = 0) records.  In order to achieve this, I am doing

```
function submissionSummary($submissions) {
    $reportArray = array();
    $totalCount = 0;
    $incompleteCount = 0;
    $completeCount = 0;

    foreach ($submissions as $submission) {

        $totalCount += count($submission);
        $reportArray["total"] = $totalCount;

        if($submission['isCompleted'] === "0") {
            $incompleteCount += count($submission);
            $reportArray["incomplete_count"] = $incompleteCount;
        } elseif ($submission['isCompleted'] === "1") {
            $completeCount += count($submission);
            $reportArray["complete_count"] = $completeCount;
        }
    }

    return $reportArray;
}
```

I am not sure if there is a more effecient way of doing this?

Now the part I am struggling with is the number element.  This number can be anything from 1 - 9.  What I am trying to do is count the number of each number.  So I want to see how many submissions have a number element 1, how many have 2 etc.  The only way I can think of to achieve this is through a lot of if statements, which if possible I would like to avoid.

Any advice on how I can structure this properly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the submission data come from a sql statement or from another source?

Comment: It comes from a Elequent query using ->get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to drop the foreach and just do:

```
function submissionSummary($submissions){
    $report = []; // or array() if you prefer
    $report['completeCount'] = $submissions->where('isCompleted', 1)->count();
    $report['inCompleteCount'] = $submissions->where('isCompleted', 0)->count();
    $report['totalCount'] = $submissions->count();

    return $report;
}
```

Comment: I would sum $report['completeCount'] and $report['inCompleteCount'] in order to avoid one more simple select

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect

Comment: I don't think you would have any performance improvements, since it is already an object in memory and not a query for the database, but you could do that...